# IDE can intellisense protobuf-python members

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I want a intellisense of protobuf class generated in python. But the implementation of generated protobuf class are special, the code is like:

```
class X(_message.Message):
  __metaclass__ = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType
  DESCRIPTOR = _X
```

Most python IDE only can intellisense `__metaclass__` and `DESCRIPTOR` two members rather than the members defined in .proto file.

How to make it?

Comment: have you figured it out?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a recent Python version (3.7+) then you can try out my https://github.com/danielgtaylor/python-betterproto project. It generates dataclasses with proper types that VSCode, PyCharm, and others can use to provide type hints & intellisense.

For example, given this input:

```
syntax = "proto3";

// Some documentation about the Test message.
message Test {
    // Some documentation about the count.
    int32 count = 1;
}
```

You would get output like this:

```
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# sources: int32.proto
# plugin: python-betterproto
from dataclasses import dataclass

import betterproto


@dataclass
class Test(betterproto.Message):
    """Some documentation about the Test message."""

    # Some documentation about the count.
    count: int = betterproto.int32_field(1)
```

It is much, much easier to read than the official generated descriptor classes.

Comment: I totally agree on legibility, however, with the CPP extension for the native Protobuf Python implementation there is a significant performance penalty (~8x serialization, ~30x deserialization): https://github.com/jdvor/pbwhy, https://github.com/danielgtaylor/python-betterproto/issues/314#issuecomment-1009814213