# Important functions do not show up in the type class of google cloud speech in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

Sorry in advance if I am using improper terminology when it comes to addressing aspects of code. For context, I am trying to use Google Cloud's speech to text for Python, and there seems to be an issue with some of the imports. Not all of the required functions shown in the documentation appear in a specific class. However, I have no idea why.

Here are my import statements:

```
import io
import os

from google.cloud import speech_v1
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import types
```

After those, I attempted to do the following (which is just a small sample of the code):

```
client = speech_v1.SpeechClient.from_service_account_json('client-key.json')

with io.open("recording-test-44100.flac", "rb") as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
```

The problem is, "types" does not have "RecognitionAudio()" as an option. The only options I have are as shown in the following image:

[image]

I have tried messing around with some of these options, but none of them lead to the RecognitionAudio() function and still work properly. I am fairly new to the Google Cloud Platform, so some guidance would be appreciated. For an overview of what I am trying to accomplish, I just want to transcribe an audio file using Cloud Speech.

If I need to provide any additional information, I will gladly do so. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: The libraries do some magic in the background so you can't rely on intellisense to give you the options.

Comment: @drum yes it would seem that there wasn't any real problem, just that PyCharm could not find any references in types.py. Thank you for the quick response, I have been struggling with this for a while

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IDE can intellisense protobuf-python members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579278/ide-can-intellisense-protobuf-python-members)

Answer (score 0):

There was no real issue, it was just me relying too heavily on PyCharm to make sure everything was correct. The code worked properly, it was just that Intellisense was not able to detect it. Thank you drum for teaching me that.