# Best way to create python classes for protobuf messages

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have to work with a project that uses protobuf encoded messages. There are a lots of messages and lots of fields in these messages, and Visual Studio Code's intellisense does not recognize them. Since I cannot memorize what all those fields are, I created a set of classes with class variables that mirror the message fields for each message type. I was able to do this because I did get the proto files where these messages are defined.

So I created classes like this in a separate file (module):

```
    class DeviceInfo(gmessage.Message):
    
    __slots__ = ["z"]
    
    board_serial: str = None
    device_serial: str = None
    firmware_version: str = None
    hw_compatibility_gpn = None #array of bytes
    rtc_valid: bool = None 
    flash_usage: FlashUsage = None
    battery_state: BatteryState = None
    setup_complete: bool = None
    device_key_hash = None #array of bytes
    battery_percentage: int = None
    vsn: str = None;
    firmware_git_sha_short: str = None
```

If I imported the module in my code where I used the protobuf messages, Visual Studio's intellisense worked, as long I provided a type hint. For example

```
    device_info: DeviceInfo = some_method()
```

I could place a 'dot' after the device_info variable and I would get a list of all the message fields. I would also get any docstring info I included in the class. Without the imported class, all I would get is a list of generic magic methods.

However, these classes serve no other purpose except for VS's intellisense and to help me remember all the options. That is why I put the `__slots__` option in the definition with a dummy variable 'z' (empty did not work) to reduce the memory footprint. I am not sure if the dataclass would be a better alternative.

It appears that using @dataclass(slots=True) is a far better alternative. I am hoping that importing this module encounters no overhead as the classes themselves are never instantiated.

Though it works, the approach seems very hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579278/ide-can-intellisense-protobuf-python-members   Also there is some recent development on generating `.pyi` type hint files: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2638

Comment: It looks like I am doing (effectively) the same thing - just manually